# How to approach PDEs of the type $u_t - \Delta u = f(t,x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I'm thinking of a way to approach the problem $u_t - \Delta u = f(t,x)$, here note that $f$ doesn't depend on $u$, it just depends on $t$ and $x$, for example $f(t,x) = t^2x^2$, so I don't see how to establish a result of existence via the fixed point theorem, maybe you can do something with Galerkin's method. But if you know, can you refer me to a paper or book in which something has already been done about this equation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle

Comment: Good! thank you!